# Entity Framework object limitations in aggregate LINQ query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, anonymous-types

I have a rather complicated query that I'd like to have return some particular types.  Mostly concerning date / time calculations or string values, the Entity Framework seems to be spitting the dummy when I try anything further than a System.DateTime type:

> The specified type member 'Date' is
>   not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and
>   entity navigation properties are
>   supported.

The query in question is:

```
    // Here comes the aggregate query.
    object summary = from te in ctx.TimeEntries
                     where te.StartTime >= startofweek
                     && te.UserName == User.Identity.Name
                     group te by te.StartTime.Day into Groups
                     select new
                     {
                         Key = Groups.Key,
                         Count = Groups.Count(),
                         //Total = Groups.Sum(n => (double)((n.EndTime ?? DateTime.Now) - n.StartTime).TotalMinutes / 60),
                         Tasks = from t in Groups
                                 orderby t.StartTime descending
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Name = t.Task.TaskName,
                                     Project = t.Task.Batch.Project.ProjectName,
                                     Batch = t.Task.Batch.BatchName,
                                     //Minutes = ((t.EndTime ?? DateTime.Now) - t.StartTime).Minutes,
                                     Start = t.StartTime.Date,
                                     Stop = t.EndTime,
                                     Description = t.Notes,
                                     Breaks = t.BreakFor ?? 0
                                 }
                     };
```

In the query above, the property "Start" will fail with the aforementioned error.  However, if I simply have "Start = t.StartTime" everything will be fine.  Similarly, the commented out value for "Minutes" will also cause problems.

Suggestions most welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use supported members in L2E queries, and [`Date` isn't one of those](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx).

One workaround is to break your single L2E query into one L2E query followed by one LINQ to Objects query:

```
var q = from e in Context.Entities
        select new
        {
            Id = e.Id,
            DateTime = e.DateTime
        };

var r = from e in q.AsEnumerable()
        select new
        {
            Id = e.Id,
            Date = e.DateTime.Date
        };
```

Comment: That probably wouldn't be such a bad thing given how verbose the query is to begin with anyway.  I'll give it a shot and see how it looks.  Thanks.

Comment: Yup, it worked a treat.  Didn't make my code more elegant, but certainly provided the freedoms I was after.  Thanks again.