# Nesting objects into a single class using MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oop, model-view-controller

I am using MVC with the Entity framework where all the database tables become objects. I am relatively new to full OO programming but I need advise on the following.

I have one data type (table) which then needs to pull in lots of information from other tables to construct a full record.

For example:
I have a item called "Building". Each building has one "manager" and a collection of "floors". So far I am creating a new class which contains all these objects. See below:

```
   public BuildingComplete
   {
       public building _building;
       public manager _manager;
       public IEnumerable<floors> _floors;

       public BuildingComplete()
       {}
   }
```

I'm then declaring this object and defining all the elements outside the class. This seems rather messy. Ideally I'd like to create a "building" object and within that object it will go away and create all the necessary elements within it. It can do this because the "Building" object contains all the linking id's / information to query the other data tables.

I looked at creating a child of "Building" but I don't know how to set the base: "Building" from the Child.....or even if this is the right thing to do.

Any ideas / pointers will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

This is something your OR/M should do. If it doesn't, in my opinion it is useless. I am basically in love with [LLBLGen](http://llblgen.com/) for this purpose; but it costs money. As far as I'm concerned, it's the best out there and there is no point not buying it.

I would, however, be surprised to learn that the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399567.aspx) didn't [do this for you in some fashion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716685.aspx).

-- Edit: As noted by @Lazarus, most ORMs will review the relatioinships you have in your DB (foreign key relationships) and generate a hierarchy based on that. This implies that you need to have this set up (if you don't already, do it).

Comment: I suspect the problem here is less to do with the ORM and more to do with the OPs understanding of databases, keys and relationships. EF will utilise relationships within the db to associate and populate objects.

Comment: As will LLBLGen. Fair enough then.

Comment: Lazarus, you're right. I can pull all this out with Linq but I am unclear of how to best structure the classes / objects

Comment: @Billyhomebase: You mean in the database, or in code? The database structure *generates* the code by way of the ORM (Linq is not an ORM). So, the data structure (in the DB, via FKs) is what you need to solve. It should be natural as to how that works.

Comment: @Noon Silk. In the code really. I am happy with the DB and Linq for connecting and pulling out the data. I'm just trying to set up this object as efficiently as possible. I want it to work like this.     new Building(buildingID); This  object then creates a "manager" and list of "floors". However it's all wrapped up under the "Building" object. Can I not interit off the "building" object and add "manager" and "<floors>" as children? I can do this now but only by creating a new object and having all these as children

Comment: @Billyhomebase: You are barking up the wrong tree, if what you are trying to create in-code is already expressed in foreign key relationships.

Comment: @Noon-Silk: Found what I was after. An aggregated query. a'la this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264714/entity-framework-object-limitations-in-aggregate-linq-query - thanks for the help though. Problem I had was not really knowing how to ask the question.