# Can't compare dates using SQLite with EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sqlite, datetime

I'm trying to compare dates using Linq to Entities on a SQLite database. The following code works, but I need to trim off the time portion to get the correct results.

```
return (from c in Context.Car
        join d in Context.Driver on c.CarID equals d.DriverID
        join r in Context.Rides on c.CarID equals r.RideID into rideJoin
        from rides in rideJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where c.IsActive && d.IsActive 
        group rides by new { c.CarID, d.FullName, d.HireDate, d.FirstPayRiseDate } into grp
        select new MyCustomClass
        {
            CarID = grp.Key.CarID,
            Driver = grp.Key.FullName,
            NumberOfRides = grp.Count(x => x != null && x.RideDate >= grp.Key.HireDate && x.RideDate <= grp.Key.FirstPayRiseDate)
        }).OrderBy(x => x.Driver ).ToList();
```

---

I've tried using [System.Data.Entity.DBFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) like so and I get this error:

```
NumberOfRides = grp.Count(x => x != null && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.RideDate) >= grp.Key.HireDate && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.RideDate) <= grp.Key.FirstPayRiseDate)
```

> SQL logic error or missing database no such function: TruncateTime

I also get the same error with DBFunctions.DiffDays()

---

I've also tried casting to Date like so and get this error:

```
NumberOfRides = grp.Count(x => x != null && x.RideDate.Date >= grp.Key.HireDate && x.RideDate.Date <= grp.Key.FirstPayRiseDate)
```

> 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported

What gives? How am I supposed to do Date functions in Linq to Entities with SQLite??

Comment: SQLite does not have a time-truncate function named `TruncateTime`, instead use the intrinsic `DATE()` function to retrieve the `date` portion of a `datetime` value.

Comment: @Dai How do you do that in linq?

Comment: Perhaps @Dai means to create a view in SQLite with a column that uses DATE() to isolate the date part, then use the view instead of the table. I do see what you mean re: `RideDate.Date` in LINQ to Entities; it works fine for me with LINQ to SQL. Maybe another possibility might be to tweak your Ride object to add a date-only property as `RideDate.Date`, then use that in your LINQ expressions. (Just a guess, though.)

Comment: Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2264714/2144390) looks similar. Perhaps it might help.

Comment: @GordThompson [That question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264714/entity-framework-object-limitations-in-aggregate-linq-query) helped me with 1 of my queries. Unfortunately to compare 2 of the dates for another query it involved pulling back too much of the database. Also, I needed to do a ToList() on the 1st part or I got the same error.

Comment: @GordThompson I have 8 of these queries that involve dates in some way and the last 1 I ended up having to create a view that compared the dates using DATE() (as you and Dai suggested) and then returning that set so I could further search on it. Ridiculously ineffective but at least it worked without throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to trim off the time portion to get the correct results

No you don't. If you want to include the rows from `startDate` through `endDate` inclusive then just use

```
... && x.RideDate >= startDate && x.RideDate < endDate.AddDays(1)
```

(Note that the second comparison is now "strictly less than".)

Comment: This is the solution I came up with as I was writing the question. This is a workaround though, surely I should be able to do some date manipulations?

Comment: Yes but it's a good workaround since it increases the chances that the WHERE conditions of the underlying SQL query will be [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Comment: Sargable is good. However this won't work when I'm trying to compare 2 database dates. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing dates on the database ? as unix time integrs ?
in that acse you can amend your connection string to include this following config setting and it will make it easy to read the datetime value via EF.

datetimeformat=UnixEpoch;datetimekind=Utc

So something like :

```
data source=&quot;|DataDirectory|\data.sqlite&quot;;datetimeformat=UnixEpoch;datetimekind=Utc
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24323591/3660930

Comment: That didn't help. The dates are valid. Queries work fine using sqlbrowser. But I need it to work using linq