# The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.(Use Sqlie)

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, entity-framework-6

[image]> System.NotSupportedException:“The specified type member 'Date' is not

> supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and
>   entity navigation properties are supported.”

I use EntityFramework6 to Query from Sqlie,there is some worng about dateTime.

```
var test = DateTime.Now.Date;
var maxEntity=_baseService.GetList<TestNoMapping>(o => o.LastChangeTime.Date == test)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.SampleId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
public class BaseService
{
    private readonly BaseContext _baseContext = new BaseContext();


    public List<T> GetList<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where) where T : class
    {
        return _baseContext.Set<T>().Where(where).ToList();
    }
```

the `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` I have try,But it doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide your code with DbFunctions.TruncateTime that is not working?

Comment: Maybe you can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597373/the-specified-type-member-date-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-exception

Comment: Same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138124/cant-compare-dates-using-sqlite-with-ef6. Unfortunately unresolved.

Comment: Add following line to constructor of your DbContext so that you can get exact query which SQL is executing. `Database.Log = s => Trace.WriteLine(s);`

Comment: The duplicate is not the best solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do here is replace the condition by a range test: date *between* last midnight and midnight today:

```
var minDate = DateTime.Today;
var maxDate = minDate.AddDays(1);
var maxEntity = _baseService
    .GetList<TestNoMapping>(o => o.LastChangeTime >= minDate
                              && o.LastChangeTime < maxDate)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.SampleId)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The reason is that it's never a good idea to convert a database value before comparing it: it disables any indexes on the column. (See [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` method of Entity framework to match date portion as Linq will not recognize `Date` property.

Can you try below code?

```
var test = DateTime.Now;
var maxEntity=_baseService.GetList<TestNoMapping>(o => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.LastChangeTime.Date) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(test))
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.SampleId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: HuangKai already wrote in his question: the DbFunctions.TruncateTime I have try,But it doesn't work

Comment: Added sample code. Can you try this?

Comment: @peter thanks,Program throw exception "SQL logic error or missing database
no such function: TruncateTime"

Comment: @Manprit Singh Sahota the err is "LastChangeTime] >= '2017/7/27 0:00:00'" ,I changed to[LastChangeTime] >= '2017-07-27 00:00:00' ，but i  don't know how to change the code

Comment: Please provide the expected query and query that is actually executing so that I can review.

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the exception: `Date` is not supported in LINQ to Entities

You should use

```
o => o.LastChangeTime.Year == test.Year &&
     o.LastChangeTime.Month == test.Month &&
     o.LastChangeTime.Day == test.Day &&
```

instead of

```
o => o.LastChangeTime.Date == test
```

**Edit**

And change

```
var test = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

to

```
var test = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: I'll try to do as you say，Program throw exception System.InvalidCastException:“指定的转换无效。”

Comment: @HuangKai Edited my question; have a look at it.

Comment: ，I uploaded a picture about the exception